# One particular probabilistic inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

I've been studying for my exam in Probability theory and I found this exercise:
prove that for every $\lambda$ greater than 0 this inequality holds:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log(x+1)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx\geq \frac{1}{e}\log\left(\frac{\lambda +1}{\lambda}\right)$$
The left side is obviously equal to $\mathbb{E}[\log(X+1)]$, where $X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, but I don't see what right side might be. Can anyone provide me some help?

Comment: Are you looking for some special meaning for this quantity ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Is that the end of the exercise or are there follow up questions to that one ?

Comment: The whole exercise is to prove the inequality

Comment: I am not sure if this specific quantity has meaning, but often times it is interesting to have lower bound on expectations to get lower bounds on tails. You can check out the Paley-Zigmund inequality for example and see why this would become handy (if you can also upper bound the second moment).

Comment: Not sure if it helps but the RHS is $\frac1e\log(\mathbb E(X+1))$. It’s the wrong direction for Jensen though.

Comment: Please choose a more expressive title. The current title says basically nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\PM}{\mathbb P}$Let $X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ then your problem is equivalent with proving the following:
\begin{align}
\E[\log(X+1)]\geq \PM(X>\E[X]) \log\E[X+1]
\end{align}
We know that
\begin{align}
\PM(\log(X+1)\geq \log\E[X+1] ) \leq \frac{\E[\log(X+1)]}{\log\E[X+1]}
\end{align}
By Markov's inequality, hence:
\begin{align}
\E[\log(X+1)]\geq \PM(\log(X+1)\geq \log\E[X+1] )\log\E[X+1] 
\end{align}
But we also know: $$\PM(\log(X+1)\geq \log\E[X+1])=\PM(X+1>\E[X+1]) =\PM(X>\E[X])$$ (btw this manipulations is exactly what lead me to this answer) and this proves the inequality.

The only thing that we did is noticing that $e^{-1}=\PM(X>\E[X])$ and Markov's inequality.